In Azure Dev Ops, classic Editor, How to get the artifact from PR Review Build?
To be able to merge the PR, I added a PR Validation build.
When the PR is merged, a new build starts doing exactly the same thing than the PR Validation Build. I would like to get the artefact generated by the PR Validation build.
How to do that in Azure Dev Ops in Classic Editor?
Thanks

[1] When you say "a new build starts doing exactly the same thing than the PR Validation Build" - do you mean you have 2 build pipelines PR and CI ? or is the same PR pipeline?
[2] When you say "I would like to get the artefact generated by the PR Validation build" - where you want to get it ? consume in another pipeline?

in the Build pipeline which will generate an artefact that will be deployed to Azure Web App, I would like to get the artefact generated by the Build made for the PR Validation.

If you want to download the PR Validation build artifact from another classic Build pipeline, you can add the Download Pipeline Artifact task and choose the build triggered by the PR.

If you want to get the artifact generated by the PR Validation build automatedly, you can use the classic release pipeline with the Continuous deployment Pull request trigger.
Steps:

Create a classic release pipeline and add an artifact with the build as source. Choose the latest version as default.



Enable the Continuous deployment Pull request trigger



Enable the Pull request deployment trigger in the Pre-deployment conditions of the Stage.



When a new artifact generated by the PR Validation build, the release pipeline will be triggered, and it will download the artifact of the PR Validation build.


